# opening a link in a UIWebView when clicking a button in objective c

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiwebview

I want to open a web page in my application without launching Safari. I want the page to appear only when a button is clicked.

Also, how can I enable/disable a button .. I used the following and it didn't work :

Button.enabled = YES;

Comment: What doesn't work, exactly?

Answer (score 1):

You should implement [UIWebViewDelegate](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/uikit/reference/UIWebViewDelegate_Protocol) in your class and load a request inside webview using

```
-(IBAction)openLinkInWebView:(id)sender{

NSMutableURLRequest *request = [NSMutableURLRequest requestWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:@"http://yourlink"]] ;
[self.yourWebView loadRequest: request];
}
```

If you don't know how to do it then just follow [some tutorial](http://conecode.com/news/2011/05/ios-tutorial-creating-a-web-view-uiwebview/).

For hiding button you need to set the outlet properly to your `UIButton` in the User interface in order to access its properties in the code.

Answer (score 0):

You can add an action on button release with this code:

```
[button addTarget:self action:@selector(openWebview:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
```

and then define your action:

`- (void)openWebview:(UIButton *)sender {
 // open webview code 
}`